# Dynamically Creating A Core Data Model At Runtime

Tags: ios, sharepoint, core-data

Is it possible at runtime to generate a core data model from a set of entities on a server? e.g. SharePoint lists or SQL/MySQL/Parse.

I'm trying to go a dynamic route because fields in SharePoint lists/SQL/Parse may be added at any time in the future meaning the core data model version in the app has to change to match the SharePoint list on the server.  If it was possible to generate an entity (SharePoint list) in core data dynamically then the app won't break when the columns in the entity change on the server.

If this is possible does anybody have an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the reference for NSEntityDescription.  You can build up a model definition by defining entities in code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSEntityDescription_Class/NSEntityDescription.html

**Edit**

From our good friends at Cocoanetics: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/creating-a-coredata-model-in-code/

Comment: Thanks. I've already read through this. There is no example provided by Apple that I can find. 

Do you have a decent example of how to take a remote database model and create it in core data?

Comment: The Cocoanetics article is great. I think your comment,motionpotion, can be modified and answer accepted. Cheers.