# Swift: How to create a Core Data Entity in app

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I want to be able to create a new entity in the database after the user specifies the attributes in app. Is this possible?

Comment: This is quite broad. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131517/dynamically-creating-a-core-data-model-at-runtime, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29908435/create-core-data-entities-dynamically-during-runtime, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379025/customize-core-data-model-at-runtime.

Comment: To be more specific I'm creating an app that allows users to create custom workouts and then log their data. So after they create a workout I would need to create a core data entity with attributes corresponding to each exercise in the workout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create new entities on the fly while using your persistent store. You create new **instances** of existing entities. Think of an entity kind of like you'd think of a class or a struct; you don't usually declare new classes or structs while your app is running but you do create new instances of each.

The most common way to create a new instance of an entity is with `NSEntityDescription`'s method, `insertNewObjectForEntityForName(_, inManagedObjectContext:)`.

If you need an entity that defines a workout that has a customizable list of exercises, the best way would be:

1. Create a generic `Workout` entity that doesn't define any exercises directly
2. Create an `Exercise` entity that defines one exercise.
3. Add a to-many relationship from `Workout` to `Exercise` so that an instance of `Workout` can have any number of related `Exercise` instances.